# Would the result of a K-means clustering run with k = 27 equal the result of three "sub-runs", with total K = 3^3^3?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, clustering, k-means, algorithms

Suppose I want to try two K-means clustering methods. In the first one, I set k = 27, the algorithm converges, and I get some result set of centroids Y. In the second method, I want to do three "sub-runs", each with k = 3. In the first "sub-run", k = 3 and there are three groups created. In the second run, I would say, for each of the three groups in sub-run one, create three additional "subgroups". The same is true for the third run. The centroid result set here is Z.

The labels for second method would look something like this in Python:

```
>>>for run1 in [1, 2, 3]:
       for run2 in [1, 2, 3]:
           for run3 in [1, 2, 3]:
               print("".join([str(r1), str(r2), str(r3)]))

111
112
113
121
122
123
...
```

Mathematically, is there any proof that Y is identical to Z? Suppose that initial centroids are not set at random at the outset of the algorithm's running; rather, we initialize manually and maintain the centroids' initial coordinates throughout the algorithm runs.

Comment: But how do you schedule it wrt initial centroids? You've got some 27 initial centroids which you used in k=27 clustering. OK. Then, you are to run the senior level k=3 clustering. Which of the 27 centroids will you select for it?

Comment: Great point. I suppose that's a huge assumption that I now don't think can be satisfied. The second method wouldn't really work for equivalency because when you get to the third iteration, you would essentially be repeating the first method - initializing 27 new clusters, effectively eradicating the clusters found in the first two iterations.

Comment: Suppose the data have two obvious, compact, highly-separated clusters and one of them consists of just two points.  It's impossible even to carry out your "sub-run" algorithm.

Comment: Another assumption not mentioned above would be that n > 27

Comment: Also, the centroids of the first three clusters you make would not necessarily (and probably would not be) one of the final centroids. Imagine instead of 27 vs 3 * 3 * 3 you try to do 4 vs 2 * 2. Let's say the data is two dimensional and consists of four circles of radius 1 centered (-10, -3), (-10, 3), (10, -3), and (10, 3). With some assumptions, after the first run, you'd get centroids at (-10, 0) and (10, 0) and after the second run you'd get (-10, -3), (-10, 3), (10, -3), and (10, 3). Still, it would be interesting to know in what conditions the two methods are in some way equivalent.